# Fire an event on another process without knowing the process start order

Tags: c#, .net, ipc, mutex, memory-mapped-files

I need the fastest way to fire an event in other process, I know that I may use Mutex, but it is very hard to manage Mutexes when I don't know the order of starting the two processes, one of the processes may be closed or not running, I thought in using FileSystemWatcher, but it has a big overhead, then I thought in using MemoryMappedFiles, I can monitor some named memory mapped file, and fire the event when this file is exists, and delete the file when the event fired, any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an [`EventWaitHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/41acw8ct.aspx) with a name in `EventResetMode.ManualReset` mode. Make sure the application which sets it keeps it open. Note that once all handles to it are closed, the event will no longer exist and thus will revert to default.

Comment: Just to add: You need to use the constructor that takes a name in order to expose the handle to other processes.